# Разная реализация onBackPressed

Tags: android, toolbar, navigation

моя задача заключается в том что нужно одновременно использовать нажатие кнопки "назад" в тулбаре и системную кнопку "назад" но с разной реализацией.
То есть при нажатии кнопки назад, должен открываться предыдущий фрагмент, а при нажатии системной кнопки должен появится вопросительный диалог "вы действительно хотите выйти?".

Для решения как я понимаю нужно переопределить метод onbackpressed, но как заставить его определять какое из действий происходит в данный момент. 
Или возможно есть другое решение мой проблемы?

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переопределяете onBackPresed и вставляете свою логику и проверки, пока вы не вызовите super() в методе бэкПресса ничего не произойдет. Тут вы можете показать диалог и реагировать на ответ.

В другом случае вешаете слушатель на кнопку назад и возвращаете на предыдущий экран. Если это фрагменты из стека фрагментМенеджера и в стэке есть фрагменты то дергайте менеджер и вызывайте метод popBackStack()